# How to export tables and users created

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm using Oracle 11g express edition and
I have created a schema with user u1.
Then I created two more users, u2 and u3, that have different privileges on that tables, procedures, etc.
Now I want to export the schema, possibly with the users, to another PC.
I tried doing it, but I have to re-create the users and the privileges.
Is there a way to do it? thanks

Comment: You want to export the users to another PC as a series of scripts/text files, or you want to export them to an XE database on another computer?

Comment: I'd like to have the same users on another computer. I should write a guide on how to use the functions and procedures.

Comment: If you want them on another computer, you'll need to install XE on said computer. Then you can use a tool like SQL Developer to copy them over (Tools > DB Copy) or you can use a pure server tech like Data Pump to move them over. Functions and procedures have nothing to do with your original question though - I would start a new topic on that.

Comment: Isn't [`expdb`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm) sufficient for that kind of work?

Comment: should I use expdp from user sys? Because I can't use it as the user who owns the schema. @SylvainLeroux 
Do you know the exact command to use with expdp ?

Comment: It imported the objects,etc but I have to grant the privileges again to the other two users. And then I noticed that scheduled jobs are not created, so I have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Login to database as sysdba ( Need to login as sys user)

2) create virtual directory

```
create directory REFRESH as 'Some PATH that DB can Access';
```

3) expdp data from this computer(run this on command prompt)

```
set oracle_sid=XE
expdp schemas=u1,u2,u3 dumpfile=dumpfile.dmp logfile=expdp.log directory=REFRESH
```

4) Install Oracle XE on another computer( If already installed skip this step)

5) Copy dumpfile from suorce to target machine

6) Create directory as mentioned in step 2 and impdp data in TARGET XE database

```
set oracle_sid=XE
impdp dumpfile=dumpfile.dmp logfile=impdp.log directory=REFRESH
```

All procedures functions and grants will be in place.

Comment: I tried different times. And, at this moment, the best option is: Expdp command. Then I create first the users on the other computer, import with the command you suggested, and then I have to create public synonym and privileges for the other two users.

Comment: The Export was made with sysdba. Then the import as the user1 created a little before on the other computer.